# Is it futile to apply for UK Visitor Visa if country is added to red list

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, covid-19

Does it make sense to apply for a UK visitor visa if your resident country has been added to the red-list?

What are the chances for getting a visa in such cases? Has anyone here applied in such situation and successfully received a visa?

Comment: Could you clarify your purpose and proposed travel times? Like during normal times, it still depends on your length and purpose of visit, proposed dates of visit, etc. etc.

Comment: @zhantongz my purpose is to meet my gf there. I was looking to travel after Jun 21 when UK restrictions are going to be removed. I was thinking of applying in Mid may but now I am skeptical bcz India has been added to red-list

Comment: Even in these strange times the fundamentals are still relevant. Do you meet the eligibility requirements? Can you demonstrate a compelling reason to leave at the end of the visit? How are you able to leave your responsibilities/commitments in India for a visit lengthy enough to include 10 days’ quarantine? In short, is a trip now credible from an ECO’s point of view?

Comment: @Traveller I would not be allowed to enter UK as long as India is on the red-list. Let's say I was planning to travel on July 5, 2021 for 20 days. If I apply today, how much buffer the ECO is going to have considering the date of travel in 2.5 months apart. India may be removed from red-list by Mid June. It's entirely hypothetical as of now. What I am essentially asking is that keeping all other factors in favourable conditions, is ECO going to deny the visa solely on the fact that the country is added to red-list.

Comment: About the second question: it is irrelevant. The red list is not handled by immigration office. They will issue the visa on immigration merits (BTW they don't have a crystal ball, or immigration would be much simpler). It could be futile if you cannot travel, but this is a different problem (first question)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.